# Django auth_login giving Value error("cannot force an update in save() with no primary key.")

Tags: python, django, mongodb, djongo

*This Question is not similar to others who have answers.*

Recently I had changed my database engine to "Djongo" from "sqlite3". After finishing successful migrations and executing runserver command successfully, When I tried to log in Django admin I'm getting this error.

```
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'djongo',
            'NAME': 'data',
            'CLIENT': {
               'host': 'mongodb+srv://admin15:mkone1@data-cluster.cu6pe.mongodb.net/useer_db?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
            }
        }
    }
```

**Traceback Error:**

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/

Django Version: 3.1.7
Python Version: 3.9.2

Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'map.apps.MapConfig',
 ]

Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\atom_django\mapping\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "E:\atom_django\mapping\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "E:\atom_django\mapping\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\atom_django\mapping\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 410, in login
    return LoginView.as_view(**defaults)(request)
  File "E:\atom_django\mapping\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\atom_django\mapping\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\atom_django\mapping\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py", line 89, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\atom_django\mapping\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\atom_django\mapping\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\atom_django\mapping\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\atom_django\mapping\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\atom_django\mapping\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 63, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\atom_django\mapping\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\atom_django\mapping\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 142, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "E:\atom_django\mapping\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 92, in form_valid
    auth_login(self.request, form.get_user())
  File "E:\atom_django\mapping\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 132, in login
    user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)
  File "E:\atom_django\mapping\venv\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 177, in send
    return [
  File "E:\atom_django\mapping\venv\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 178, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "E:\atom_django\mapping\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 20, in update_last_login
    user.save(update_fields=['last_login'])
  File "E:\atom_django\mapping\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 67, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\atom_django\mapping\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 753, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "E:\atom_django\mapping\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 790, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "E:\atom_django\mapping\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 855, in _save_table
    raise ValueError("Cannot force an update in save() with no primary key.")

Exception Type: ValueError at /admin/login/
Exception Value: Cannot force an update in save() with no primary key.
```

- Models.py:

```
    class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.category
    
    class ProductId(models.Model):
        Pcategory = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        prod_id = models.CharField(default=1000, max_length=7)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return '%s %s' % (self.prod_id, self.Pcategory)
    
    class Product(models.Model):
        Pid = models.ForeignKey(ProductId, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        Pname = models.CharField(max_length=40)
        Pcategory = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        Data_source = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="NA")
        Vendor_field = models.CharField(max_length=80, default="NA")
        is_downloadable = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        Delivery_time = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=2)
        Punique_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, default="NA")
    
        def __str__(self):
            return '%s -> %s' % (self.Pcategory, self.Pname)
    
    
    class PriceTable(models.Model):
        prod_id = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        MinimumPrice = models.FloatField(default=400)
```

Someone Please help me.

Comment: Might be helpful: https://github.com/nesdis/djongo/issues/3#issuecomment-638643543

Comment: Also why do you need a ProductId class?
I know this is not part of the issue you are facing.

Comment: @Markonick thanks for highlighting that, I know that and was going to remove it but then though of solving this issue first

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I've already tried that but it doesn't work

Comment: The issue is in the admin application itself, it isn't compatible with your MongoDB

Comment: @mkalioby but I have seen others on yt using djongo and accessing their admin

Answer (score 1):

This is **just a workaround** and not an exact fix:

Just **remove** **all the foreign key relations from your models** and migrate again it should work fine.

So this problem was caused as Djongo doesn't support on_delete=models.CASCADE.

Just clr all the migrations then create the databases again and instead of using

```
_id=models.ObjectIdField()
```

let it be integer field as the autoincrement field with primary key which is taken care default by Django Models in the background.

Comment: hi @zen18 does this cause any issue for you during/after the project ?